# Как сделать чтоб работа шла последовательно?

Tags: java, concurrency

Есть задача чтобы в консоль вывелись данные в таком формате

Левый
Правый 
Левый
Правый 
Левый 
Правый

Код

```
    public class MainClass {
        public static  void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

            SomeHardWork someHardWork = new SomeHardWork("Левый");
            SomeHardWork someHardWork2 = new SomeHardWork("Правый");
            someHardWork.start();
            someHardWork2.start();

        }
    }

    public class SomeHardWork extends Thread {
        private String name;
        public SomeHardWork(String name) {
            super(name);
            this.name  = name;
        }

        @Override
    public void run() {
         for (int i = 0 ; i<10 ; i++){
             System.out.println(name);
         }

    }
}
```

Благодарю

Comment: Спасибо.Это то что надо!

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько вариантов, самая простой на мой взгляд (но не самый эффектиный) это использование глобального счетчика:

```
public static class SomeHardWork extends Thread {
    private static final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
    private String name;
    private final int number;

    public SomeHardWork(String name) {
        super(name);
        this.name = name;
        this.number = counter.getAndIncrement();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            while (counter.get() % 2 != number) {
            }
            System.out.println(name);
            counter.incrementAndGet();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Мм, а что насчет "немного `Thread.sleep` в `while`"?

Comment: и что он будет выводить последовательно левый правый ?)

Comment: Операция быстро выполняется, смысла нет делать переключение контекста

Answer (score 1):

Можно обойтись одним лишь монитором, используя wait и notify.

```
public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Object monitor = new Object();

        SomeHardWork someHardWork = new SomeHardWork("Левый", monitor);
        SomeHardWork someHardWork2 = new SomeHardWork("Правый", monitor);
        someHardWork.start();
        Thread.sleep(100); //Даем возможность начать левому
        someHardWork2.start();

    }
}

class SomeHardWork extends Thread {
    private String name;
    private Object monitor;

    public SomeHardWork(String name, Object monitor) {
        super(name);
        this.name = name;
        this.monitor = monitor;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            synchronized (monitor) {
                System.out.println(name);
                monitor.notify();
                try {
                    if (i != 10) {
                        monitor.wait();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: а не знаете ка это сделать через Executor

Comment: Thread.sleep(100); - на практике это работает  как надо, но в теории это не решение, тк возможны ситуации когда второй поток начнет работать первым